# Resolving dependencies in angular application by condition

Tags: angularjs

A am planning to implement base angular module `base` and 2 child modules `m1` and `m2`. In module `base` will be implementation of all services, directives and controllers. In modules `m1` and `m2` will be different implementations of services, controllers, directives with the same names.

In my application will be 2 almost the same editors, but also will be differences in implementations of services, directives or controllers.

Imagine I have controller in `base` module

```js
function IndexCtrl($scope, userService) {

}
```

But in modules `m1` and `m2` are different implementations of `userService`.

I am developing SPA with `ui.router` and start application with `ng-app` directives.

```js
angular.module('test', ['base', 'm1', 'm2'])
```

```html
<html ng-app="test">
</html>
```

Service `userService` will be resolved depending on order of modules in `test` module definition.

How can I manage of resolving dependencies in this case?
I can't use provider, because base module doesn't know anything about children modules. Also I can't use `angular.bootstrap`.

Comment: What condition should decide which module is used? Where is this condition available?

Comment: Here condition - concrete editor, in the first i would like to use implementation from the first module (m1), in the second one - form the second module (m2).

Answer (score 0):

Currently AngularJS **doesn't handle namespace collisions for services**, which means, you've got 2 different modules with the service named the same way and you include both modules in your app, only one service will be available. And as you just said, the service will be resolved depending on the order of modules injection.

A proper way to solve this is adding prefix for services instead of using totally the same name.

Comment: But I can't add prefix to names, because it breaks by references in my IndexCtrl.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two modules that have colliding namespaces. But if the condition is constant and available at an early state, you can register the right set of services and directives:

```
var userService1 = function(...) {...};
var userService2 = function(...) {...};

var module = angular.module("m", []);

if (condition) {
    module.service("userService", userService1);
} else {
    module.service("userService", userService2);
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Modules are loaded in index page and used in others.